# Large Seamless Scrolling Background in SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, loops, background, sprite-kit

Okay, so i'm fairly new to SpriteKit, but so far it's been a lot of fun working with it. I'm looking for a way to have a large scrolling background loop endlessly. I've divided my background into small chunks to let SK call as it needs them, using this code:

```
    for (int nodeCount = 0; nodeCount < 50; nodeCount ++) {
    NSString *backgroundImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sky_%02d.gif", nodeCount +1];
    SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:backgroundImageName];
    node.xScale = 0.5;
    node.yScale = 0.5;
    node.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
    node.position = CGPointMake(nodeCount * node.size.width, self.frame.size.height/2);
    node.name = @"skyBG";
```

and I'm able to move this whole block just fine in `update`, but I can't get it to loop seamlessly. or at all, for that matter. I've tried the method suggested elsewhere on here that takes a copy of the background and takes it to the other end to give the appearance of a seamless loop, and no dice here. I've also tried adding this to the end of the above code, which I had hoped might work:

```
        if (nodeCount == 49)
    {
        nodeCount = 0;
    }
```

but that just cause the simulator to hang, so I assume it's inadvertently creating a loop or something. Any assistance at all would be great! I feel like there's a simple fix, but I'm just not getting there... thanks a bunch, folks!

**UPDATE**

here's the code I'm currently using to get the background to scroll, which works just fine:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

_backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(_backgroundNode.position.x - 1, _backgroundNode.position.y);
```

}

So to sum up: I have a moving background, but getting it to loop seamlessly has been challenging because of the size of the background. If there's anything at all I can do to help clarify, let me know! Thanks a bunch

Comment: If you put that conditional in that loop, you will have a endless loop, because `nodeCount` will always be below 50. Why not try a tutorial on scrolling ? Your code suggests you don't understand some fundamental concepts about what you are trying to do. For example, if you are scrolling the background, where does the position of a given node change each frame? If it never changes, it won't scroll. That code will result in each node being assigned the same location every frame.

Comment: If there is scrolling code that you aren't showing, that's the relevant code we need to see. This sentence is puzzling - "I'm able to move this whole block just fine in update, but I can't get it to loop seamlessly. or at all, for that matter." So is it moving ? or not ?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, it is moving, right now just using a simple code inside the update method:
    1_backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(_backgroundNode.position.x - 1, _backgroundNode.position.y);`

the problem is getting it to loop back around. There's methods I have had success with making a seamless looping background, but the whole image from the above code I would like to use is over 6000px long, so I broke it up into smaller chunks for SpriteKit to arrange. But I can't get it to loop back.

Comment: If I'm still not making sense, let me know what I can do to better clarify! Thanks!

Comment: What I am saying is that if you want help with your scrolling code, update your question with your scrolling code. What you want to do is very logical, so break it down and think it through logically. comments is not the right place for your code, just makes it incredibly difficult to read ;)

Comment: gotcha, will do. Thanks!

Comment: You have the background cut into 50 nodes correct ? The code you posted only moves one node called _backgroundNode. Are the nodes children of that node ? I don't see the correlation between the code you posted with 50 nodes and the code in your update method. This is a bit like coding charades at the moment. Without full context, I don't know how you expect anyone to be able to help you. (Short of just coding it for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example of the logic you can employ to achieve a scrolling background. It is by no means a final or ideal implementation, but rather a conceptual example.

Here is a simple scroller class :

```
// Scroller.h

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

    @interface Scroller : SKNode
    {
       // instance variables
        NSMutableArray *tiles;  // array for your tiles
        CGSize tileSize;    // size of your screen tiles
        float scrollSpeed; // speed in pixels per second
    }

    // methods 
    -(void)addTiles:(NSMutableArray *)newTiles;
    -(void)initScrollerWithTileSize:(CGSize)scrollerTileSize scrollerSpeed:(float)scrollerSpeed;
    -(void)update:(float)elapsedTime;

    @end
```

Implementation :

```
// Scroller.m 

#import "Scroller.h"

@implementation Scroller


-(instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        tiles = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)addTiles:(NSMutableArray *)newTiles
{
    [tiles addObjectsFromArray:newTiles];
}

-(void)initScrollerWithTileSize:(CGSize)scrollerTileSize scrollerSpeed:(float)scrollerSpeed
{
    // set properties
    scrollSpeed = scrollerSpeed;
    tileSize = scrollerTileSize;

    // set initial locations of tile and set their size
    for (int index = 0; index < tiles.count; index++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *tile = tiles[index];

        //set anchorPoint to bottom left
        tile.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        // set tilesize
        // this implementation requires uniform size
        [tile setSize:tileSize];

        //calcuate and set initial position of tile
        float startX = index * tileSize.width;
        tile.position = CGPointMake(startX, 0);

        //add child to the display list
        [self addChild:tile];
    }
}

-(void)update:(float)elapsedTime
{
    //calculate speed for this frame
    float curSpeed = scrollSpeed * elapsedTime;

    // iterate through your screen tiles
    for (int index = 0; index < tiles.count; index++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *tile = tiles[index];

        // set new x location for tile
        tile.position = CGPointMake(tile.position.x - curSpeed, 0);

        // if new location is off the screen, move it to the far right
        if (tile.position.x < -tileSize.width)
        {
            // calculate the new x position based on number of tiles an tile width
            float newX = (tiles.count -1) * tileSize.width;
            // set it's new position
            tile.position = CGPointMake(newX, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

In your scene , init your scroller  :

```
-(void)initScroller
{
    // create an array of all your textures
    NSMutableArray *tiles = [NSMutableArray array];
    [tiles addObject:[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:skyTexture]];
    [tiles addObject:[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:skyTexture]];
    [tiles addObject:[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:skyTexture]];
    [tiles addObject:[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:skyTexture]];

    // create scroller instance (ivar or property of scene)
    scroller = [[Scroller alloc]init];

    // add the tiles to the scroller
    [scroller addTiles:tiles];

    // init the scroller with desired tile size and scroller speed
    [scroller initScrollerWithTileSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768) scrollerSpeed:500];

    // add scroller to the scene
    [self addChild:scroller];

}
```

In your scene update method :

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime 
{

    float elapsedTime = .0166; // set to .033 if you are locking to 30fps

    // call the scroller update method
    [scroller update:elapsedTime];
}
```

Again, this implementation is very barebones and is a conceptual example.

Comment: Gotcha, that'll definitely get us started. Thanks a bunch! That little simulator smoothing deal is pretty clever also. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Well, I only just learned that iOS devices are locked to a vsync. So it actually should be just set to .0166 and if you are getting a constant 60fps. Otherwise lock to 30fps - .033  updating the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a library for a tile scroller, is using a solution similar to the one provided by prototypical, but using a Tableview datasource pattern to ask for the nodes. Take a look at it:

[RPTileScroller](https://github.com/raspu/RPTileScroller)

I take some effort to make it the most efficient possible, but mind I am not a game developer. I tried it with my iPhone 5 with random colors tiles of 10x10 pixels, and is running on a solid 60 fps.